# Xamarin Ios webview dynamic url string

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Im not sure if the post title is the correct way to explain myself, I am trying to pass in a string url from my datasource into the Variable 'url' to load a webpage.
It works perfect if I just write `var url = "http:google.com"`, but not when I enter the binding.

Again I'm not sure if I'm handling the string correctly between screens, any help would be great on learning at the minute.

```
using Foundation;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System;
using UIKit;
using NWRestaurantGuide.Core;

namespace NwRestaurantGuide
{
    public partial class WebPage : UIViewController
    {
        public WebPage (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }
        public Restaurant SelectedRestaurant
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        UIWebView webView;

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            Title = "WebView";
            View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

            webView = new UIWebView(View.Bounds);
            View.AddSubview(webView);

            var url = SelectedRestaurant.Website; // NOTE: https required for iOS 9 ATS
            webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(url)));

            // if this is false, page will be 'zoomed in' to normal size
            webView.ScalesPageToFit = true;


            // iOS 9 ATS docs
            // http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios9/ats/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is the problem that if you set the SelectedRestaraunt property after you've created the page, that it does not update the webview with the new url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are three issues here

first, you need to be able to pass a value to WebPage.  You can do that by using PrepareForSegue in your RestaurantDetailViewController

```
    public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
    {
        base.PrepareForSegue(segue, sender);

        if (segue.DestinationViewController is WebPage)
        {
            WebPage web = (WebPage)segue.DestinationViewController;

            web.SelectedRestaurant = this.SelectedRestaurant;
        }
    }
```

second, your WebPage needs to act on that value

```
    public Restaurant SelectedRestaurant
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    UIWebView webView;

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        webView = new UIWebView(View.Bounds);
        View.AddSubview(webView);

        if (SelectedRestaurant != null)
        {
            var url = SelectedRestaurant.Website;
            webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(url)));
        }
    }
```

finally, you need to be sure your urls are valid:

```
good:  http://www.google.com
bad:   www.google.com
```

Comment: Hey, thanks but I think I'm implementing your code wrong, I no longer get an error though just a blank white page now, do I set the this in my view controller or models? cheers for your help

Comment: this is a modification to the WebPage code you posted

Comment: Aye cheers that's what I thought, it doesn't work. It does open a view without any errors with just a blank white screen though. Should I be using the prepare for segue method on the previous screen with the button that opens the webview?

Comment: it's hard to say without seeing more code.  Have you tried debugging to see if the updateWeb() method is getting called?

Comment: Sorry Jason I feel really stupid here, IM only learning but how can I debug to test if the method is being called should I put it into a debug.writline(); ?

Comment: that's one way, or learn to use the debugger.  That's a fundamental programming skill you need to learn.  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-studio/debugging_with_xamarin/

Comment: HI Jason, I was wondering if you could look at the code if I put it on Github?

Comment: sure, I can do that

Comment: Thanks for this Jason any help would be great, the GitHub link is: https://github.com/kepbem/xamarin-ios-test

Comment: see revised answer

Comment: Hey thanks very much for this I was thinking that I needed to use the prepare for segue, just don't know enough yet. Thanks again.

Comment: HI Jason, Its working perfect thank you for your help. I was wondering if you had a second would you know why my rest service is not being picked up when I change over to the DerryRestaurantRepository.cs?